# Exact formula of the roots of a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots, radicals, closed-form

I'm looking for a closed formula given one (or all) root of a polynomial $P=aX^4 +bX^3+cX^2+dX+e$.

I'm not interested in the efficiency of such a formula. On the contrary, I would like to show my students that this formula is very complicated.

Comment: You can search for the Cardano's formula.

Comment: And solving the quartic equation

Comment: @PeterForeman That's it, thanks ! You can make it an answer if you wish (what about also copying the image here instead of juste pointing to the webpage)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#/media/File:Quartic_Formula.svg) is below which should also work for the cubic case.
[image]